# Programmatically create a realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Some advice given on this page indicate that it is a good idea to shard databases. In part it also states: "Store data in siloed database instances, grouped by user or data type". The page describes how to create multiple realtime database instances using the Firebase console.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding

I am looking for a way to programmatically create these databases either by the Admin SDK (using Node.js). Or even using the rest API.

I have read a number of guides, but I can't figure out how to get started.

This sort of says how to create an app programmatically, but I do not necessarily see how to create a realtime database within a project.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project?platform=web

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase provides a [REST API for the management of Firebase projects and services](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest).  However, creation of a new database shard is not included in this API.  However, please feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).